# HighCharts load data via Json

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to make a HighCharts chart from my Json Data.
Here is my Json Data

```
[{"ReadData":"99","Time":"07\/09\/2015 00:00:07"},{"ReadData":"101","Time":"07\/09\/2015 00:01:07"},{"ReadData":"113","Time":"07\/09\/2015 00:02:07"},{"ReadData":"115","Time":"07\/09\/2015 00:03:07"},{"ReadData":"96","Time":"07\/09\/2015 00:04:07"},{"ReadData":"103","Time":"07\/09\/2015 00:05:07"}]
```

My problem is when that the graph don't load , what am i doing wrong?
Here is my code HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
     <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['Time'];
        options.series[0] = json[0]['ReadData'];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
    </script>         
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: json[0]['Time'] to be replaced with  json[0].Time; better if you can share fiddle of your problem. initialize an Array and put Time and other values in it and then call in highcharts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a couple of issues, see working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ux74929j/5/

Let me explain:

- your format is not compatible with Highcharts, and you are trying to use this in a wrong way, parse your data first:

  ```
          var categories = [],
             points = [];

          $.each(JSON, function(i, el) { // Assuming that JSON is data from getJSON()
              categories.push(el.Time);
              points.push(parseFloat(el.ReadData)); // Another issue - data should be number, not string
          });
         options.xAxis.categories = categories;
         options.series[0].data = points;
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  ```
- you don't have `xAxis` in options, but you are trying to assign `categories` anyway:

  ```
     var options = {
         chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'spline'
         },
         xAxis: {},
         series: [{}]
     };
  ```

So, to sum up, your code should looks like this:

```
       var options = {
           chart: {
               renderTo: 'container',
               type: 'spline'
           },
           xAxis: {},
           series: [{}]
       };

       $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
           var categories = [],
               points = [];

            $.each(data, function(i, el) {
                categories.push(el.Time);
                points.push(parseFloat(el.ReadData));
            });
           options.xAxis.categories = categories;
           options.series[0].data = points;
           var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
       });
```